# Error 404 for rest webservice request in offline app in GeneXus Ev3 U9

Tags: genexus, genexus-sd

I'm developing an offline Android app with **Genexus Ev3 U9** and when I try the app in the device I see there is no initial synchronization, even when I try to execute a manual sync the app shuts down. The cat log shows that request made to URLs like `http://192.168.12.17/MyAppSmartDevicesEnvironment/gxmetadata/MyApp.android.json` 
worked fine but when the app tries to get this URL `http://192.168.12.17/MyAppSmartDevicesEnvironment/rest/MyAppOfflineDatabase?fmt=json&event=gxchecksync` **returns 404** I tried the same link in my laptop and it's like the requested resource was not created by GeneXus.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are actually a couple of things you might want to check.
When you accessed `http://192.168.12.17/MyAppSmartDevicesEnvironment/gxmetadata/MyApp.android.json` you got data but that just means that the virtual directory was successfully created. (which is good of course)

Then you need to check if the WCF module is installed correctly, in order to do that you could try to go to `http://192.168.12.17/MyAppSmartDevicesEnvironment/MyAppOfflineDatabase.svc/rest` or any other service in your KB. That goes straight to the service implementation. (you can check you web.config file in order to see the actual rewriting rules)

If that works it's certainly a URL Rewrite problem like Sandro and Guscarr suggested.

You can download and install the module from here: http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Comment: The URL Rewrite was properly installed and working fine; the problem was on WCF that wasn't completely enabled. I'm working on Windows 10 and all the checks related to WCF must be selected.  Thank you all, I wasn't considering WCF as a possible cause.

Answer (score 0):

Gcastano,

It seems that you're generating to .net, right?

If so, it could be some problem with iis rewrite module.

Anyway you might check gx software requirements...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that REST services cannot be run on your IIS, as Sandro said, try installing URLRewrite.
Further info at http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?14575,Android%20-%20FAQ%20and%20Common%20Issues